# Vpn icedtea plugin

Tags: vpn

Id like to connect to my work through checkpoint vpn by browser for this i nead to install java component plugin - icedtea - is  this plugin available in ubuntu 15.04 as default? or i need to download it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. Try

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```